# oracle db storing image blob in database with GWT

Tags: java, sql, oracle, gwt

I am using the upload GWT to upload an image and then trying to store that into the database. client side selects image, and then its passed to the http servlet where that class is trying to insert into database.

It wont update the table column with the image, but I created a test byte array with some text it will go into the column.

The table column is

[image]

**When i created the column i didnt specify a size.**

I wont post client code because i dont think it will be helpful here. As the byte array is getting to the servlet just fine.

Here is the servlet class

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {

    long maxFileSize = 20480;
    long sizeInBytes = 0;
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

    String entityId = request.getParameter("entityId");
    int id = Integer.parseInt(entityId);



    try {

        List items = upload.parseRequest(request);

        Iterator iter = items.iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

            //handling a normal form-field
            if(item.isFormField()) {
                System.out.println("Got a form field");
                String name = item.getFieldName();
                String value = item.getString();
                System.out.print("Name:"+name+",Value:"+value);

            } else {

                //handling file loads
                System.out.println("Not form field");
                String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                String fileName = item.getName();
                if (fileName != null) {
                    fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fileName);
                }

                String contentType = item.getContentType();
                boolean isInMemory = item.isInMemory();
                 sizeInBytes = item.getSize();


                    byte[] data = item.get();

                    API.GetAccountManager().saveLogo(id, data);
```

The database is locally and i am in the dev environment.
I am able to write out the image to the tomcat folder so i know the byte array is correct. The image size is 10kb. data byte array size is 10705

debugging  i see that the image is first stored in a temp folder in tomcat.

Here is the class with the calling method.

```
public void saveLogo(final int accountID,  byte[] data){

            Statement stmt = null;
            Connection connection;
            int rowCount;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

            try {
                connection = API.GetConnection();
                pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                        "UPDATE account SET LOGO = ? WHERE account.id = ?");

                byte[] testBytes  = "this is a test".getBytes();
                //  pstmt.setBytes(1, data);
               pstmt.setBinaryStream(1,new ByteArrayInputStream(data),data.length);
              //  pstmt.setBinaryStream(1,new ByteArrayInputStream(testBytes),testBytes.length);
                pstmt.setInt(2, 5);
                 rowCount = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                 pstmt.execute();
                 connection.commit();
            }catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                if (exception instanceof DatabaseException) {
                    throw (DatabaseException) exception;
                }
                throw new DatabaseException("There was a problem executing a database call.", exception);
            } finally {
                if (pstmt != null) {
                   // pstmt.close();
                }
            }
}
```

This class still needs some work.  I am able to insert testBytes, but 0 rowCount get updated with the byte[] data.

Why wont this work with the actual image, but works with some simple text?

Comment: Oracle store short data in the record. If the data is larger than 4096 -  I might not remember it correct - it will be stored in the LOB, i.e. outside the record. Can you change the size of your test byte array to 10K and try again?

Comment: yeah, let me try it and i will post my results

Comment: it doesnt like the array to be bigger. I added some more text to make its 196kb and it doesnt insert

Comment: As suspected.  Which version of Oracle and the driver are you using?

Comment: I will have to let you know tomorrow. I was able to shrink an image to 150 bytes and it went in. Anything larger doesnt work. Do i need to specify a size when i made the column?

Comment: please check back tomorrow, morning

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production and driver:. ojdbc14-10.2.0.1.0.jar

Comment: Since I don't have Oraclle DB in my environment, please check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A81042_01/DOC/java.816/a81354/oralob2.htm

Comment: I will check it out, thanks for taking the time to help me